# SSHFS: Cannot umount / re-mount remote directory after connection is interrupted

Tags: ubuntu, mount, remote, sshfs

I often use sshfs to mount a remote directory to make it appear as local:

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other myname@server:/remote/path /mnt/remote/
```

Occasionally there could be interruption to the connection so `/mnt/remote` will appear as empty. If I try to re-run the above command, I'd get

```
'/mnt/remote:' Transport endpoint is not connected'
```

However I'm unable to (force) unmount the directory either:

```
sudo umount (-f) /mnt/remote
umount: /mnt/remote: target is busy
```

I'm wondering what can I do to re-mount the directory without rebooting my machine?

Comment: I tried adding the flags `-o reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=15,ServerAliveCountMax=3` in sshfs but doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sudo umount -l /mnt/remote` seems to work.

Got this answer from a friend.
-l stands for lazy and I wouldn't have guessed the solution by myself.

Comment: So weird that this works and -f does not

Answer (score 0):

You should find out which process is keeping the mountpoint busy. For example this:

```
lsof /mnt/remote
```

will list those processes (there could be many).

You then end them (normal close, or `kill` as shutdown would do) and try to unmount again `sudo fusermount -u /mnt/remote`)

Comment: with `sudo lsof /mnt/remote`, I'm only getting `lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.sshfs file system /mnt/remote
      Output information may be incomplete. lsof: status error on /mnt/rescomp: Transport endpoint is not connected` which doesn't appear to be showing any processes.

Comment: This means that your sshfs is not connecting to anything.  So since you are not connected to anything there cannot be any processes acting upon that connection.  Reboot and I believe the problem will solve itself.